# List comprehension variable referenced before assigned

Tags: python, json, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate a list based on [this JSON](https://github.com/mapzen/metroextractor-cities/blob/master/cities.json):

```
city_list = [
    city
    for city in metroextractor_cities['regions'][region]['cities']
    for region in metroextractor_cities['regions']]
```

Python says the variable `region` is referenced before assignment:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'region' referenced before assignment
```

I don't really see that. What is wrong with my list comprehension?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have your loops the wrong way around; they should be listed in *nesting order*, from left to right:

```
city_list = [
    city 
    for region in metroextractor_cities['regions']
    for city in metroextractor_cities['regions'][region]['cities']]
```

Now `region` is set in the 'outer' loop, so that the 'inner' loop can use it.